# Chaining callbacks within promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a factory function that triggers an `$http` request. This function itself accepts success callback and error callback functions (`successCallback` and `errorCallback`)...

```
var makeRequest = function(options, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $http(options)
    .then(function() {
      // do success things
      successCallback();
    }, function() {
      // do error things
      errorCallback();
    });
};
```

Is this the recommended way of handling subsequent callbacks (`successCallback` and `errorCallback`)?

My intuition says 'no', but I'm obviously missing some conceptual understanding here...

I had thought the following would be more appropriate

```
var makeRequest = function(options, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $http(options)
    .then(function() {
      // do success things
    }, function() {
      // do error things
    })
    .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
};
```

but this calls `successCallback` even when there was an error in the `$http` request.

Any help...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to abstract `makeRequest` function to be free of any callbacks notion. It just makes request and returns promise. It's up to consumer how to handle this promise, subscribe to success or error callbacks or not.

```
var makeRequest = function (options) {
    return $http(options).then(function () {
        // do success things, construct data if needed to resolve promise with
        return data;
    }, function () {
        // do error things, construct error object if needed to reject with
        return $q.reject(data);
    });
};

makeRequest({url: '/something', method: 'GET'}).then(function() {
    // success callback
}, function() {
    // error callback
});
```

Comment: I like how this looks, however it seems similar to my original alternative, and it's still giving me the same problem as my original alternative (see second code snippet in my question (`.then(...).then(...)`)) wherein errors from the original request are still causing the successCallback function to be called...am i missing something?

Comment: Ah! I see your latest edit now includes the `return` with the $q.reject().  That's what I was missing.  Success!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rather than `return $q.reject(data)` isn't the standard way to reject to just `throw` which will be turned into a rejection automatically?